# Nodejs callback response not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, post, callback

I'm trying to authenticate a user based on values entered in a given form. However, after using `res.send()`, the function at AngularJS controller is not able to correctly redirect user even if the password and username are correct. Am I handling the callbacks correctly?

**Controller**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("loginController", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.sub = function() {

    var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-
    urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

    $http.post('/login', { data:{ username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password} })
      .then(function(response){
            if(response.state==0){
                 console.log('Error!');
            } else if(response.state==1){
     console.log('action on success');
     window.location.href = '/views/success.html';}
   }).catch(function(error){
     console.log('action on error');
   });
```

**Authentication**

```
var db = require('../../config');

exports.login = function(req,res){

var username = req.body.data.username;
var password = req.body.data.password;

db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',[username], function 
(error, results, fields){
var result = "0";
if(error) {
console.log('Code 400, Error ocurred');
}   

else{

    if(results.length>0){

    if(results[0].password == password){
        console.log('Code 200, login sucessful');
    res.json({ state : 1});

    }
    }
else{
   console.log('Code 400, Password or username invalid');
 res.json({ state: 0})
  }
}

});
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var db = require('./config');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
require('./app/routes')(app);


app.listen(3000,function(err){

if(err){

console.log(err);
}
else{

console.log("Listening on port 3000");
}

});
```

**Route.js**

```
var auth = require('../app/middleware/authenticateUser');

module.exports = function (app) {


app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');


});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){


auth.login(req,res);

});


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `state` is not a property of the `response` object. For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage).

Comment: This is a programming website, not a "debug my broken code" website. Learn how to use the developer console. A simple `console.log(response)` would show the problem. Give us the result for `console.log(response.status)` and `console.log(response.data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $window in your controller and then in your successful  response

```
$window.location.href = '/views/success.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although using the $window service is considered AngularJS best practice, I don't think this is where the problem is.

Have you tried `console.log()` the response object of the $http call?

Maybe the problem is because you put `if(response.state)` instead of `if(response.data.state)`.